# Bluetooth Windows Phone Communicating with the device after the app terminates

Tags: windows-phone-8, bluetooth

I am working on an app which send's and receive message from a embedded device through Bluetooth using stream-socket . Here is my problem if the user closes the app in the middle of communication the the connection between the Bluetooth device and phone is getting terminated. Is there any way to still make connection alive and process the message.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, when the user leaves the application, it is either terminated or suspended. In either case your app cannot work when it is not active. It even won't work under lock screen by default and that is something you must explicitly enable.